# Swapping elements

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I want to swap elements of an array, so I created a method to do it.
The method takes an integer array, and two indices, it then swaps the elements at the given indices. however, I'm not sure on what to do past the declared variables. I'm don't know if a loop is necessary for this method, however I added it. Here's the code.

```
public static int[] swapElement(int[] a, int i1,int i2) {
    int temp=i1;
    int swap=temp;
    for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        if (a.length>i1) {
            temp=i2;
        }
    }

    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I cannot understand what your code should do, but proper swap should look like this:

```
public static void swapElement(final int[] a, final int i1, final int i2) {
    final int temp = a[i1];
    a[i1] = a[i2];
    a[i2] = temp;
}
```

of course you can add boundary checking or create new array instead of doing changes in passed one

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public static int[] swapElement(int[] a , int i1, int i2)
{
    int temp = a[i2];
    a[i2] = a[i1];
    a[i1] = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to swap an array element using method I recommend you to instantiate a global array variable.

```
int arr1[] = new int[length];
int arr2[] = new int[length];

public static void swapElement(final int i1, final int i2) {
{
    int temp = arr1[i1];
    arr1[i1] = arr2[i2];
    arr2[i2] = temp;
}
```